# Issue regarding navbar-wrapper class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This might be a noob question. I am currently using Bootstrap but changing semantics of my HTML markup to avoid direct usage of Bootstrap classes. I had used the following class to wrap my navigation bar -

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper navbar-default"></div>
```

Now while substituting the above classes with my own (and compiling my custom .less file), 'navbar-wrapper' class comes as 'undefined' which is fine since I cant find it in the 'bootstrap.css' file.

But then how come using the 'navbar-wrapper' class in the above snippet gives no error ?
And it does cause a change in style too cause using 'navbar' instead of 'navbar-wrapper' adds border around my navigation bar !

**Edit 1**: Complete relevant code for clarity

```
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1><a href="dummywp.html">Dummy Blog</a></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="dummy.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Buzz</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: your code incomplete, so it's difficult to determine whether your class inherit the rule from the parent class

Comment: @xnome Added more code !

Comment: i see no border, [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ltfy/)

Comment: what is the point of the navbar-wrapper class? if you want the bootstrap stuff to work alone with having that class you need both navbar navbar-default classes then you can add whatever class you want. otherwise your navbar-wrapper class needs to take the place of the bootstrap one

Comment: @xnome I am saying using navbar instead of navbar-wrapper adds a border. Modified the demo u created, it does add a border

Comment: i've tested it before, .navbar does add rule to set the border, the demo was according to the code you subscribe above, that's why it's not showing any border, but if you change it into .navbar instead, it will show you a thin border of 1px solid black

Comment: @theporchrat navbar-wrapper is the bootstrap class I am talking about. It removes the border and radius of the navigation bar. The main issue is it is not present in the bootstrap.css but still seems to work. This in turn causes problems when I use it in the custom .less file I compile